# Does either have the same meaning: "ther's no point (in)"/"it's no use"?

Tags: gerunds

Having made a little research previously, made up my opinion that these constructions ("there's no point (in)"/"it's no use") are used in the same way, so that it'd be correct to say:

> There is no point in (it's no use) giving up at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those are both correct. Personally I would use ***There is no point in*** giving up at all.